# Changing Impresspages to use SMTP

Tags: php, smtp, sendmail

I need to change the code below that belongs to Impresspages CMS to use SMTP instead of sendmail. How can I do this?

```html
<?php
/**
 * Queue controls the amount of emails per hour.
 * All emails ar placed in queue and send as quiq as possible.
 * Parameter "hourlyLimit" defines how much emails can be send in one hour.
 * If required amount of emails is bigger than this parameter, part of messages will wait until next hour.
 *
 * @package ImpressPages
 *
 *
 */
namespace Ip\Internal\Email;
/**
 * Class to send emails. Typically all emails should be send trouht this class.
 * @package ImpressPages
 */
class Module
{
    /**
     * Adds email to the queue
     *
     * Even if there is a big amount of emails, there is always reserved 20% of traffic for immediate emails.
     * Such emails are: registration cofirmation, contact form data and other.
     * Newsletters, greetings always can wait a litle. So they are not immediate and will not be send if is less than 20% of traffic left.
     *
     * @param string $from email address from whish an email should be send
     * @param $fromName
     * @param string $to email address where an email should be send
     * @param $toName
     * @param $subject
     * @param string $email email html text
     * @param bool $immediate indicate hurry of an email.
     * @param bool $html true if email message should be send as html
     * @param array $files files that should be attached to the email. Files should be accessible for php at this moment. They will be cached until send time.
     * @internal param $string @fromName
     * @internal param $string @toName
     */
    function addEmail($from, $fromName, $to, $toName, $subject, $email, $immediate, $html, $files = null)
    {
        $cached_files = [];
        $cached_fileNames = [];
        $cached_fileMimeTypes = [];
        if ($files) {
            if (is_string($files)) {
                $files = array($files);
            }
            foreach ($files as $fileSetting) {
                $file = [];
                if (is_array($fileSetting)) {
                    $file['real_name'] = $fileSetting[0];
                    $file['required_name'] = basename($fileSetting[1]);
                } else {
                    $file['real_name'] = $fileSetting;
                    $file['required_name'] = basename($fileSetting);
                }
                $new_name = 'contact_form_' . rand();
                $new_name = \Ip\Internal\File\Functions::genUnoccupiedName($new_name, ipFile('file/tmp/'));
                if (copy($file['real_name'], ipFile('file/tmp/' . $new_name))) {
                    $cached_files[] = ipFile('file/tmp/' . $new_name);
                    $cached_fileNames[] = $file['required_name'];
                    $tmpMimeType = \Ip\Internal\File\Functions::getMimeType($file['real_name']);
                    if ($tmpMimeType == null) {
                        $tmpMimeType = 'Application/octet-stream';
                    }
                    $cached_fileMimeTypes[] = $tmpMimeType;
                } else {
                    trigger_error('File caching failed');
                }
            }
        }
        $cachedFilesStr = implode("\n", $cached_files);
        $cachedFileNamesStr = implode("\n", $cached_fileNames);
        $cachedFileMimeTypesStr = implode("\n", $cached_fileMimeTypes);
        $email = str_replace('src="' . ipConfig()->baseUrl(), 'src="', $email);
        Db::addEmail(
            $from,
            $fromName,
            $to,
            $toName,
            $subject,
            $email,
            $immediate,
            $html,
            $cachedFilesStr,
            $cachedFileNamesStr,
            $cachedFileMimeTypesStr
        );
    }
    /**
     * Checks if there are some emails waiting in queue and sends them if possible.
     */
    function send()
    {
        $alreadySent = Db::sentOrLockedCount(60);
        if ($alreadySent !== false) {
            $available = floor(ipGetOption('Email.hourlyLimit') * 0.8 - $alreadySent); //20% for immediate emails
            $lockKey = md5(uniqid(rand(), true));
            if ($available > 0) {
                if ($available > 5 && !defined('CRON')) { //only cron job can send many emails at once.
                    $available = 5;
                }
                $locked = Db::lock($available, $lockKey);
            } else {
                $available = 0;
                $locked = 0;
            }
            if ($locked == $available) { //if in queue left some messages
                if (ipGetOption('Email.hourlyLimit') - ($alreadySent + $available) > 0) {
                    $locked = $locked + Db::lockOnlyImmediate(
                            ipGetOption('Email.hourlyLimit') - ($alreadySent + $available),
                            $lockKey
                        );
                }
            }
            if ($locked) {
                $emails = Db::getLocked($lockKey);
                foreach ($emails as $key => $email) {
                    if (function_exists('set_time_limit')) {
                        set_time_limit((sizeof($emails) - $key) * 10 + 100);
                    }
                    $mail = new \PHPMailer();
                    /*          $mail->Sender = $email['from'];
                     $mail->addCustomHeader("Return-Path: " . $email['from']);*/
                    $mail->From = $email['from'];
                    $mail->FromName = $email['fromName'];
                    $mail->AddReplyTo($email['from'], $email['fromName']);
                    $mail->WordWrap = 50; // set word wrap
                    $mail->CharSet = ipConfig()->get('charset');
                    $mail->Subject = $email['subject'];
                    /*  foreach($this->posted_files as $file){
                     if(isset($_FILES[$file]['tmp_name']) && $_FILES[$file]['error'] == 0){
                     $mail->AddAttachment($_FILES[$file]['tmp_name'], $_FILES[$file]['name']);
                     }
                     }*/
                    $files = explode("\n", $email['files']);
                    $fileNames = explode("\n", $email['fileNames']);
                    $fileMimeTypes = explode("\n", $email['fileMimeTypes']);
                    $fileCount = min(count($files), count($fileNames), count($fileMimeTypes));
                    for ($i = 0; $i < $fileCount; $i++) {
                        if ($files[$i] != '') {
                            if ($fileMimeTypes[$i] == '') {
                                $answer = $mail->AddAttachment($files[$i], $fileNames[$i]);
                            } else {
                                $answer = $mail->AddAttachment(
                                    $files[$i],
                                    $fileNames[$i],
                                    "base64",
                                    $fileMimeTypes[$i]
                                );
                            }
                            if (!$answer) {
                                ipLog()->error(
                                    'Email.addAttachmentFailed: {subject} to {to}',
                                    array(
                                        'to' => $email['to'],
                                        'subject' => $email['subject'],
                                        'filename' => $fileNames[$i],
                                    )
                                );
                                return false;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    if ($email['html']) {
                        $mail->IsHTML(true); // send as HTML
                        $mail->MsgHTML($email['email']);
                        try {
                            $altBody = \Ip\Internal\Text\Html2Text::convert($email['email']);
                        } catch (\Ip\Internal\Text\Html2TextException $e) {
                            $altBody = $email['email'];
                        }
                        $mail->AltBody = $altBody;
                    } else {
                        /*$h2t = new \Ip\Internal\Text\Html2Text($content, false);
                         $mail->Body  =  $h2t->get_text();*/
                        $mail->Body = $email['email'];
                    }
                    $mail->AddAddress($email['to'], $email['toName']);
                    $mail = ipFilter('ipSendEmailPHPMailerObject', $mail, $email);
                    if (!$mail->Send()) {
                        ipLog()->error(
                            'Email.sendFailed: {subject} to {to}',
                            array('to' => $email['to'], 'subject' => $email['subject'], 'body' => $email['email'])
                        );
                        return false;
                    }
                    if (sizeof($emails) > 5) {
                        sleep(1);
                    }
                    Db::unlockOne($email['id']);
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236) and [Are job offers spam?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276249/are-job-offers-spam)

Comment: In particular, please note that offers of payment are not permitted. (See the second Meta post I linked to for more details on that specific policy).